# Secure REST Unauthenticated Account Creation

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest

I'm designing a REST API and I've hit somewhat of an odd point. 99% of this API will be secured, but there are a few functions that need to be publicly accessible. These pertain to account creation, and initial password setting. Once they have credentials, they can access the rest of the API.

The endpoint that allows a user to create a new account via a signup form is unauthenticated. Securing this endpoint isn't really possible because I'm using AngularJS on top of nodejs, and dog-fooding my API via AJAX calls. This means I can't hide credentials anywhere to access the AccountCreation endpoint. Currently, I have the webform make an AJAX call to another endpoint and create a token that says to form is valid. Upon submission that token is validated, then removed from the database. However, this token endpoint is obviously visible in code, so not much security there. Email verification is used to 'activate' the account, then the user is given a one-time link to set their initial password, which also resides on an unauthenticated endpoint(but requires the token sent in the email).

I guess my worry is someone spamming the 'CreateAccount' endpoint, and making a bunch of accounts. In reality I guess they could simply do this via the webform as well. Is this a valid security concern? How do most places handle unauthenticated account creation webforms?

Edit: the final application will be run over https

Comment: They use HTTPS. You can encrypt, do some stuff that makes it unreadable to the naked eye etc etc but if you don't use HTTPS connection, none of these matter.

Comment: HTTPS communication isn't going to hide the endpoint URL from the page source.

Comment: Account creation is often rate-limited by IP to reduce effectiveness of such attacks, as well as monitored for unusual behaviour. If you are worried about being a target because new accounts could have value to attackers (e.g. as platforms to spam other users), then you are not alone, and need to look at a variety of techniques used by sites (such as SO) used to limit effectiveness of automated account creation.

Comment: A new account would have a low value, since it is essentially useless until the customer onboarding process is completed, which requires at least one phone call. I will certainly look in to rate-limiting.